# Make 9 AIs to replace Supreme Court justices

Tags: robots

Since the supreme court is always political, why not program 9 AI robots that use different methods to determine whether a law is constitutional and the outcome of cases. How would engineers go about building this? Would it work?

Comment: [AI is sending people to jail—and getting it wrong](https://www.technologyreview.com/s/612775/algorithms-criminal-justice-ai/)

Comment: [This is how AI bias really happens—and why it’s so hard to fix](https://www.technologyreview.com/s/612876/this-is-how-ai-bias-really-happensand-why-its-so-hard-to-fix/)

Answer (score -1):

Politics are driven by a combination of things such as culture, ideology, religion, ethics, morality, desire for money, fame, and power, etc.  Although God has one truth, most people don't know this truth, a few do, and the rest either disagree about it or just don't believe in Him. The Constitution was written by man.  It does not tell us what to do in every situation. It is open to interpretation.  A person's interpretation of the Constitution is driven by his morality, culture, and all the things I mentioned above. AI systems are designed by people so they are driven by their biases.

Comment: 'Although God has one Truth', how did you make this assumption, especially in a website that deals with technology and science?

Comment: It isn't my assumption but the definition of God.  God is perfect and therefore has a perfect truth.  For how can there be truth that conflicts with itself?  Can you have 0=1?  Yes=no?  Science was born from philosophy but they were originally one and the same.  This is why scientists who earn a doctorate, typically earn a Ph.D. (doctor of philosophy).

Comment: To have an unbiased AI system means you must know the truth and societies in general can't agree on the truth.

Comment: Explain the conflict.